# R function that requires 2 arguments but takes 3

Tags: r

I am building a function in R that calculates the pythagorean of a triangle. The function can take 3 arguments: a,b,c. However, it requires that only 2 of them be inputted, or it throws an error, since a Pythagorean can only be calculated with 2 sides. How do I make a function that 3 inputs but only requires 2?

Comment: Put in your code, we can't detect any issue if you don't provide your code here.

Comment: added the check

Comment: You can put: `pythagorus <- function(a, b, c=NULL)`

Comment: No, it will also work if either a or b are NULL. But you should name your arguments when calling the function. `pythag(a=1, b=3)` or `pythag(b=1, c=3)`.

Comment: Say I put in arguments a and c. This would spit the error "argument b is missing with no default

Comment: You're right. You need to assign them all as NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign default values to arguments within your argument list to prevent the error. In this case, assign NULL to all.

```
pythag <- function(a=NULL, b=NULL, c=NULL) {
  if(length(c(a, b, c))!=2)
    stop("You must supply exactly 2 of a, b and c")
...
}
```

If you wanted to add *other* checks, such as numeric values, you can do these individually:

```
  if(is.null(a) && is.numeric(b) && is.numeric(c))
    return(sqrt(c^2 - b^2))
  else if(is.null(b) && is.numeric(a) && is.numeric(c))
    return(sqrt(c^2 - a^2))
  else if(is.null(c) && is.numeric(a) && is.numeric(b))
    return(sqrt(a^2 + b^2))
  
  print("All arguments must be numeric")
}
```

Comment: Ah I see that works. Now, however, I have a check in my code that requires all inputs to be numbers. This method would return an error that not all inputted values are numeric when I call it.

Comment: `if(is.null(c) & is.numeric(a) & is.numeric(b))` etc...

Comment: You'll have to provide the __full code__ of the function in your question, otherwise it's difficult to help you with _other_ problems. Read the very first comment above. This works for me: `pythag(1, 3)`